# Adding HTML5 offline support to a Rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, offline, assets

I want to add HTML5 offline support for my Rails 3.1 app, and I've come across [rack-offline](https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline), a gem suited for this purpose. However, rack-offline only adds the assets in the `public` folder to the application cache manifest file. How do I have it also add all the compiled assets from my `assets` folder (the ones that the asset pipeline generates)?

---

Specifically, I have the following in my `routes.rb` file:

```
offline = Rack::Offline.configure do
  cache "images/masthead.png"

  public_path = Rails.public_path
  Dir[public_path.join("javascripts/*.js")].each do |file|
    cache file.relative_path_from(public_path)
  end

  network "/"
end
```

The same way that I have the `Rails.public_path`, can I get a path to the compiled assets? That way I can use the above code to add the files in that path to the cache manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first things first, I believe this bit of code should be place inside an initializer since it is just configuration:

```
Rack::Offline.configure do
  cache "images/masthead.png"

  public_path = Rails.public_path
  Dir[public_path.join("javascripts/*.js")].each do |file|
    cache file.relative_path_from(public_path)
  end

  network "/"
end
```

To answer your question about serving your compiled assets they are accessible from the browser so all you need to do is provide a cache statement manually and things should work. Try using a configuration like this:

```
Rack::Offline.configure do
  cache "assets/application.js"
  cache "assets/application.css"   
  network "/"
end
```

Comment: Cool, and how do I cache the home page, so that `http://example.com/` will work offline but `http://example.com/signup` has to go through the network?

Comment: Never mind, looks like the above configuration does exactly that. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I take that back, it didn't case the home page. How do you make it cache the home page?

Comment: You would want to add a cache directive for the home page, you should be able to add the path to the homepage like so `cache "home/index"` Edit: Hmm since thats a root url, im not sure... one sec

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry, but I take back what I took back. It DOES work, the problem wasn't with the cache manifest but rather with iOS. Looks like it caches the root url by default. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and wrote a gem to solve the assets MD5 fingerprint problem.

https://rubygems.org/gems/assets_offline

Comment: Does it works in rails 3.2? I'm newbie and reading in github. Thank you.

Comment: Not tried it, my apps are all on 3.1 but I cant see any reason why it wouldnt work

Comment: Thanks! Actually I'm using it in my rails 3.2 apps. They works properly!